# MongoDb java driver projection performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, find, slice, projection

I have encounter probably a problem using MongoDB like this. I have 860000 documents in a collection and have 500 collections like this. I have 3 columns, first and second field is type of Array contains 10 elements, third is type of Int64 that keeps currentTimeMillis. When i query 1000 document from one table it tooks ~2500 ms. But when i execute same query getting only first elements of two fields (using $slice operator for Array) (each other contains 10 elements), it takes ~2000 ms. This looks weird. MongoDB is in remote host, so i take approximately 10 times smaller data from network but it takes almost same amount of time. Any thoughts?

Comment: do you have index for this field?

Comment: yes. there is index on time field. i query using mongo java driver. in java side i use long type for currentTimeMillis. but in mongoDB this field is Int64. Can this lead to not use index, i dont know. this is another issue for this problem.

Comment: explain the query and it will give you information about index usage.

Comment: there is no explain method of find.

Comment: collection.find(whereQuery).projection(fieldQuery);    this is query in java side.

Comment: i try it on robomongo, yes it uses index on insertTime.

Answer (score 0):

Problem turns into this :) When i query 1000 documents using collection.find(whereQuery), it takes ~2400ms. But when i query 13 documents using same code, it takes ~1500ms. Data taken 100 times smaller but time even not half. Am i missing something.